# TLS 1.2 Not showing by default in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-registry, schannel

It is my understanding from reading this article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn786418.aspx#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS12

That in the registry TLS 1.2 should be enabled by default on Windows Server 2012 R2.

However, checking the registry on our webservers, this key is missing?

I am using AWS EC2 boxes with the vanilla Windows Server 2012 R2 AMI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I used this website to see what was enabled on our website. Might be worth a try: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe "enabled by default" means the key doesn't have to exist for it to be turned on.  You only need to add the value if you want to disable it.

Comment: That makes sense then, thank you for your answer, I guess my issue must be in the application not the server

Answer (score 5):

[IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) is a great tool for easily seeing what protocols and ciphers are enabled on your server

Comment: Thanks, I did download that and try it in Dev but was reluctant to drop the exe and poke around on live.